# RuntimeError: Split pattern data/* does not match any files

Tags: airflow, tfx

I'm currently trying to convert the [TFX-TFRS tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/ranking_tfx) into an Airflow pipeline.
When I run this Pipeline with LocalDagRunner() it executes without error. When I use the AirflowDagRunner() it throws the following error (Airflow pipeline is triggered through the Airflow Web-UI):

> RuntimeError: Split pattern data/* does not match any
> files.

Inside the data folder resides a CSV dataset.
I use the standard CsvExampleGen component in both cases.

This is the path to the dataset, which gets ingested by the pipeline:

```
PIPELINE_NAME = 'TFRS-ranking'

# Directory where MovieLens 100K rating data lives
DATA_ROOT = os.path.join('data', PIPELINE_NAME)
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by providing the Airflow pipeline with the absolute path to the data, instead of the relative path.